# CF10 query multiple rows for jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, coldfusion

I have a CF10 function that I am trying to figure out how to display assoc_last, assoc_first ( Last Name, First Name ) for an autocomplete. I have been able to display either the first name or last name but for some reason cannot figure out how to set up the array to accept both. Would anyone be able to help guide me in where I may be going wrong?

```
<cffunction name="queryNames" access="remote" secureJSON="false">
        <cfargument name="searchPhrase">

        <cfquery name="query_names" datasource="dsn">
           SELECT assoc_userid, assoc_last, assoc_first FROM table
           WHERE assoc_status = 'ACTIVE' 
        </cfquery>

        <cfset result = arrayNew(1) >

        <cfloop query="query_names">
            <cfset ArrayAppend(result, query_names.assoc_last)>
        </cfloop>

        <cfreturn result>
    </cffunction>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#name").autocomplete({
                source: function(query, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "redirects/autocomplete.cfc?method=queryNames&returnformat=json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            searchPhrase: query.term
                        },
                        success: function(result) {
                            response(result);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Tried:

```
    <cfquery name="query_names" datasource="dsn">
       SELECT CONCAT(assoc_last, ' ', assoc_first) AS `whole_name` FROM table
       WHERE assoc_status = 'ACTIVE' 
       and assoc_last NOT LIKE 'Test%' 
       and len(assoc_last) > 0 
       ORDER BY assoc_last
    </cfquery>

    <cfset result = arrayNew(1) >

    <cfloop query="query_names">
        <cfset ArrayAppend(result, query_names.whole_name)>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn result>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Concatenate first name and last name in the query and try that.

Comment: yep i just broke it lol

Comment: This is for JQueryUI's autocomplete right? Most examples I've seen put the query info into a struct first. Here's a working Git Repo that returns several bits of information at once. https://github.com/trosenow92/JQuery-UI-AutoComplete-in-ColdFusion

Comment: yes it is unfortunately my CF is garbage :(

Comment: That git repo I linked is something I modified myself. You can see an example on my project site here: http://nbawherearetheynow.com/ - type in 'CHA' and it should give you a couple names. Is that the functionality you're looking for?

Comment: yes i have two others that are hardcoded with JS but I want a name one for employees from the database but the database has it split last name first name

Comment: Can you add a sample response?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan i just get a white screen do you see any errors in the sql query?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan it worked I had a syntax error

Comment: Now i have a new problem though guess i have to write another question ... the searchphrase when you start typing the name doesnt get rid of the other names that dont qualify all names stay there the whole time

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan around whole_name i had to remove the qoutes post the answer since you helped me come up with that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464505/cf10-jquery-autocomplete-drop-down-names-not-sorting-through-the-text-the-user-i if any one may be able to assist

Comment: @DavidBrierton -  I provided an exact working example of the functionality you seek, what's the dealio?

Comment: @TRose sorry i just keep getting little errors in mine that I am trying to get kinked out

Answer (score 0):

```
<cffunction name="queryNames" access="remote" secureJSON="false">
        <cfargument name="searchPhrase">
            <cfquery name="query_names" datasource="dsn">
               SELECT assoc_last + ' ' + assoc_first as whole_name, assoc_userid  FROM table
               WHERE assoc_status = 'ACTIVE'
               AND ( assoc_last like 'searchPhrase%'
                     or assoc_first like 'searchPhrase%')
           </cfquery>
        <cfset resultSTRUCT = {
                'resultcount' = 0,
                'items' = arraynew(1)
            }/>
      <cfif query_names.recordCount>
        <cfset resultSTRUCT.resultcount = query_names.recordcount/>
        <cfloop query="query_names">
             <cfset arrayappend(resultSTRUCT.items, { 
                        "whole_name" = "#whole_name#"
                        ,"id" = "#assoc_userid#"
                    })/>
        </cfloop>
      </cfif>
     <cfreturn result>

</cffunction>
```

Comment: Wish i could say this worked but the drop down doesnt even appear with this :(